# What are the advantages of using f(x) instead of y=x.

Tags: functions

Yeah, It's a pretty simple question. The only thing I know is that it is far more convenient and clear as to what is being inputted. ex.

```
F(x)=x+3
F(2)=5
```

the input was 2, output was 5. 
Are there any other advantages or is that all?

Comment: If you are plotting in two dimensions $y=x^2$ highlights the co-ordinates, and curves like $x^3+3xy+y^3=0$ make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are asking. A number of points which may be relevant:

1. Most usually, writing "$y=\text{some expression dependent on x}$" (I suppose that's what you meant) is not quite formal. For instance, if $y = x+2$ then apparently $x+2=y$ and probably also $x=y-2$, but now it looks as if $x$ was a function of $y$, not vice versa.
2. It's usually good to have a handle on the function, in separation of concrete input. If you say $f(x) = x^2$ then it makes sense to say that $f$ is differentiable. If you say $y=x^2$, there is no good way to say the above.
3. If you have two functions $f$ and $g$ on the same domain, you can quite naturally speak of $f \cdot g$ or $f + g$, or the family of all functions of the form $a f + b g$ with $a,b$ integers. I don't suppose your other approach makes writing these things easy.